# C#/WinForms Создание двух форм в различных потоках и вызов функции одной формы в другой

Tags: c#, winforms

такой вопрос. Нужно создать две функционирующие формы между которыми буду передаваться данные по протоколу Udp. Формы создаются в двух различных потоках, все корректно. Но есть потребность вызова функций в одной форме из другой, соответственно из одного потока в другом,а также использование переменных одной формы в другой. Компилятор конечно не даёт так сделать, подскажите пожалуйста, как это обойти, если можно с примером кода.

Comment: Куча вопросов и неверных суждений, могу аргументированно прокомментировать каждое ваше слово. Но вот только вы не сказали, а что сделать то хотите. Суть форм? Зачем 2? Зачем UDP? Почему именно UDP? Расскажите, что хотите написать, быть может уже написанное есть.

Comment: `Формы создаются в двух различных потоках, все корректно.` как именно? Почему вы решили, что в разных? Насколько мне известно, в рамках одного приложения это сделать очень сложно, да и не нужно это делать. В UI приложении есть только 1 поток, предназначенный для UI. Покажите код, у вас что-то странное происходит в нём, хотелось бы понять, что именно.

Comment: Не-не-не! Если уж вы взялись за работу по протоколу UDP, то забудьте об использовании переменных.

Comment: Вообще суть задания, есть две формы клиент-сервер грубо говоря, на одной форме один пользователь рисует что-то на PictureBox, и это в тот же момент передаётся на другую форму, где все отрисовывается.

Мало знаком вообще с многопоточностью и работой с сетями, так что извиняюсь если что, за глупые вопросы.

Comment: @Adamovichhh в таком случае это не просто "две формы", а два отдельных приложения с общей архитектурой, при которой одно явялется сервером, а другое клиентом