# С#/WinForms Передача компонента формы по протоколу Udp

Tags: c#, winforms, tcp, udp

такой вопрос. Существует два проекта на WinForms, связь между ними осуществляется по протоколу Udp. На каждой форме есть компонент pictureBox. Такой вопрос, как можно передать состоянии компонента pictureBox одного проекта, другому, по протоколу Udp.

С помощью System.Drawing рисую на одном pictureBox и нужно отрисовывать на другом. В общем реализую приложение, по типу игры Крокодил.

Comment: Сериализовать и передать как [массив байтов](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7350732/19188974), потом десериализовать из байтов.

Comment: @Bicqzzv11e bf.Serialize(ms, sendingObject), при данном вызове вылазит вот такая ошибка - System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: 'Type 'System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox' in Assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=5.0.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' is not marked as serializable.'

Comment: Вы не можете сериализовать контрол или неуправляемый объект типа битмапа, сериализовать можно только то что подлежит сериализации, например ваша собственная модель данных. Но вы можете битмап сохранить в массив байт (примеров полинтенета, `bmp.Save`+`MemoryStream`) и его передать, затем на другой машине его из этого массива байт загрузить обратно. Даже можете сжимать в PNG при сохранении для экономии трафика.

Comment: вам стоило отредактировать [старый вопрос,](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1415430/c-winforms-%d0%a1%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d1%85-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc-%d0%b2-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%85-%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d0%b2) а не создавать новый

Comment: _С помощью System.Drawing рисую_ - как и что именно рисуете? Если выводите Bitmap - это одно, а если рисуете линии и т. п. - это другое. Про первый случай уже сказали. А во втором можно передавать команды с параметрами и повторять их в другом приложении.